# Reporting on Octopus Deployment steps

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is it possible to report on / query the data that is displayed here (red arrows in screen shot below) for individual octopus deployment steps? I have looked at the database schema and their RESTful API but don't see anything. I am trying to generate a report that aggregates time spent for each process across deployments.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information presented here is calculated from the task log. You can access the task log via the API at `/api/{spaceId}/tasks/{taskId}/raw`

For example:

```
                    |   == Success: Step 1: Run a Script ==
01:04:18   Verbose  |     Run a Script completed
                    |   
                    |     == Success: Worker ==
01:04:12   Verbose  |       Octopus Server version: 2022.3.425
01:04:12   Verbose  |       Environment Information:

-- snip ---

01:04:18   Verbose  |       Successfully finished Run a Script on a Worker
                    |
```

From the Task Log view:
[image]

There is some examples of interacting with the API for tasks in the [OctopusDeploy-Api](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api) repo, such as [this one](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/blob/master/Octopus.Client/LINQPad/Get%20task%20details%20for%20all%20deployments%20of%20a%20release.linq) to get task details.